# Powershell script- send email to all users that are outputted

Tags: sql, powershell, email, send

This is my code below-
I am new to Powershell so Im looking for a way to send an email to all the users that are outputted and also send an an email to myself with the CSv file of output?

```
get-module azuread
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
 $dt = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -Top 100000 | Where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "*gmail.com"} | Select UserPrincipalName,ObjectId
$Users | ForEach-Object {
Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where {$_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp -le $dt} 
$user = $_
Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $user.ObjectId | ForEach-Object {
$Result += New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
DeviceOwner = $user.UserPrincipalName
DeviceName = $_.DisplayName
DeviceOSType = $_.DeviceOSType
ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp = $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp 
IsCompliant = $_.IsCompliant
}
}
}
```

thANK YOU

Comment: Look up `Send-MailMessage`.

Comment: As aside, make things easier for yourself by **indenting** code.